# Outlook 2013 conditional not working

Tags: html, css, html-email

I have the following condititonal to apply styling to outlook clients only

```
<!--[if mso]>
    <style>
        .myClass{
            color: #000000 !important;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

I've also tried:

```
<!--[if if gte mso 9]>
```

If I remove the condition the styling is applied. I've tried removing any other styling on the page and that doesn't resolve it.

I am testing it on Outlook 2013 as part of office 365 (screenshot of outlook info)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have spelt the CSS property `color` as "coloir" - are you sure it is not due to this?

Comment: Thanks, this is a typo within the question. It is correct within the file.

Comment: Okay, I just thought I'd point it out (I've spent many wasted hours debugging things which have been simple typos!).

Comment: Although helpful insight, this is not an answer. Instead, it should have been a comment.